# How to get transparency in certain areas of UIView subclass with drawRect override

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I've got a `UIView` subclass with `drawRect` overridden.  The drawing code does not fill the whole area of the view; some of it is meant to be transparent.  But when it draws onscreen, what should be transparent is black.  **How do I get it to be properly transparent?**

If I set the `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`, the whole view disappears.  If I set it to any other color, the black area changes to that color.  Setting `opaque` to `NO` has the same effect.  If I draw a transparent rectangle at the start of `drawRect` like below:

```
[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
UIRectFill( rect );
```

...then it goes to black again.  I can use another color in the above code and it draws that color.  If I make the color I use partially transparent, I can see the black showing through.

**UPDATE:** It may be relevant that my view has transparency gradients.  I tried testing with a really simple `UIView` subclass that just draws a blue rectangle inside its bounds and leaves everything else transparent.  Setting that view to `opaque=NO` renders as expected.

Comment: In your drawRect, do you call CGContextClearRect(context, rect);?

Comment: @MattWilding: No.  And I have tried setting `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` to yes and no to no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view's `opaque` has to be set to `NO` and `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`.  Also, the wrong blend mode was being used.  We had:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
```

We needed:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOver);
```

The drawing code was generated by a graphics tool that can output code, and their support department figured out that the wrong blend constant was being generated because of an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line of code to initizlize your view.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self.layer setOpaque:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and you can set alpha property to make transparent effect

```
self.alpha=0.3f;
```

Comment: I tried setting both the view and its layer to `opaque=no`.  No dice.  See my update for more information: my view has transparency gradients.